# I can create query on MS Access and retrieve data from server with sql statement Got error with pass-trough query?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have SQL Server developer edition installed on my laptop. I can create query on Microsoft Access and retrieve data from server with this sql statement:

```
SELECT Products.* 
FROM Products 
IN '' [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=DIMITRIPC;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=NORTHWIND;TABLE=dbo.Products];
```

But when I try to do the same with Pass-Through query I get error:

> ODBC -- call failed
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'. (#156)

I don't want to have link tables, just to retrieve data from code with temp query. Any help would be great. Thank you.

I already have ODBC connection and working dns file.

Comment: That IN clause in a PT query would make no sense because with a PT query the query is processed within SQLServer. I do not have IN clause in my PT query and works just fine.

Comment: Connection string must be placed in query ODBC Connect Str property. How are you building PT query? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42

Answer (score 0):

With a simple query, the `IN` clause is working fine—but with a pass-through query, the connection string must be put into query properties:

ODBC Connect

```
Str = "ODBC;DSN=NORTHWIND;UID=dimit;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=NORTHWIND;Network=DBMSSOCN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't post another question - Edit your existing question.

So, follow these steps:

Open up the PT query, and set the connection string here like this:

[image]

Note that the query you use will now be T-SQL (SQL server syntax).

So, bring up the property sheet for the pass though query, and enter your valid connection string into the ODBC Connect Str.

You not use any "in" clause, and in fact can place any valid T-SQL statement in the Access query editor. In fact, your not even limited to select commands, but can enter quite much any valid T-SQL command you wish.